# How to continue in If else in lambda expression?

Tags: python, if-statement, filter, conditional-statements, continue

I wanted to **continue** in the **else** section of the lambda expression in filtering. Is it possible? if it is then how?

```
filter_testing = list(filter((lambda element: element if 'w' in element else continue), lst_check))
```

Comment: there's no `for` or `while` loop to `continue` -- what behaviour do you want?

Comment: sorry but yes there isn't, but my question is, as lambda expressions go through each element one by one over an iterator during filtering, is it possible to continue if I want some elements to be omitted if the *if condition* didn't meet? I know the solution is putting *'w' in element*, but it's just a question that arose during finding the solution. Sorry if my question is too basic, I am a total newbie and still learning the basics. Thank you for your answer though. :)

Comment: @Villicus Why are you adding an `if` in the first place? I think you're just confused about how `filter` works.

Answer (score 1):

The function passed to filter should return a boolean, not the element:

```
filter_testing = list(filter((lambda element: 'w' in element), lst_check))
```

See: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_filter.asp

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I have already found that solution, I was just wondering whether if it is possible to continue inside **if-else** of a **lambda** expression. All I found that if is use **'if'** then I have to deliver an **else** with a return value within a lambda expression. I guess it is not possible. Thanks again for the answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

You can supply False in case the condition is not met:

```
list(filter(lambda element: element if "w" in element else False,
            ["with", "or", "without", "you"]))
```

Result (in Python 3.9.13):

```
['with', 'without']
```

A hint by this sentence in the docs:

> If *function* is `None`, the identity function is assumed, that is, all
> elements of iterable that are false are removed. [Python docs: Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

Comment: That only happens to work in this case; see [Nicolas's answer](/a/70721244/4518341). For a counter-example, say I want to select the elements that *don't* contain `'w'` from this list: `L = ['time', 'work', '']`, then I should get `['time', '']`, but instead I get `['time']` because the empty string is falsy. Code: `list(filter(lambda element: element if "w" not in element else False, L))`